Limitation in calculations with Metapost
With the value i = 60 (with color blue), the curve is not drawn but with pgfplots, there is no problem.
I compiled with lmtx
      \startMPpage[offset=1DK]

      numeric u;
      u = 6cm;
      
      interim linejoin := mitered;
      interim ahangle := 30;
      
      path xx, yy;
      xx = ( (-0.3,0) -- 1.4 right) scaled u;
      yy = ( (-0.1,0) -- 1.8 right) rotated 90 scaled u;

      def compute_curve(suffix f)(expr xmin, xmax, xinc) =
          ((xmin,f(xmin))
          for x=xmin+xinc step xinc until xmax:
               .. (x,f(x)) 
          endfor)
      enddef;

      
      for i = 1 upto 4:
      
      vardef f(expr x) =x+exp(-i*x) enddef;

      path curve;

      curve = compute_curve(f,-0.4,1.4,0.0001) scaled u;

      draw curve;

      endfor;
     
      vardef f(expr x) =x+exp(-6*x) enddef;

      path curve;

      curve = compute_curve(f,-0.4,1.4,0.0001) scaled u;

      draw curve;

      vardef f(expr x) =x+exp(-15*x) enddef;

      path curve;

      curve = compute_curve(f,-0.4,1.4,0.0001) scaled u;

      draw curve;


      vardef f(expr x) =x+exp(-60*x) enddef;

      path curve;

      curve = compute_curve(f,-0.4,1.4,0.0001) scaled u;

      draw curve withcolor blue;


      drawarrow (0,0) -- (u,0) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5bp;
      drawarrow (0,0) -- (0,u) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5bp;

      
      label.urt("A",(0,1u));
      
      draw xx; 
      draw  yy;

      draw (1u,0) -- (1u,1.8u);
      
    
      label.llft("0",(0,0));
   
      path rectangle;
      rectangle = (-0.3u,-0.4u) -- (1.3u,-0.4u) -- (1.3u,-0.4u) -- (1.3u,1.4u) -- (-0.3u,1.4u)--cycle;

      clip currentpicture to rectangle;
     \stopMPpage


Your example is far from minimal which makes it a bit tedious to check. I would start by changing the step length from 0.0001 to something more reasonable. Maybe 0.01.

@mickep I shortened the code a bit but changing the pitch doesn't work. The value i = 20 seems to be the maximum possible value.

Doesn't it work with the "double" number system of MetaPost?

There is something fishy, the plot disappears in some zoom levels. I will probably need to update this answer after more inspection.
Note that you can use the built-in function, no need for your own macro.
\startMPpage[offset=1DK]

  numeric u;
  u = 6cm;

  vardef f(expr x) =x+exp(-60*x) enddef;

  def compute_curve(suffix f)(expr xmin, xmax, xinc) =
      ((xmin,f(xmin))
      for x=xmin+xinc step xinc until xmax:
           .. (x,f(x))
      endfor)
  enddef;

  path curve;

  curve := function(1,"x","x + exp(-60*x)",epsed(-0.4),epsed(1.4),0.001) scaled u ;
  draw curve withpen pencircle scaled 3 withcolor darkblue ;

  curve := compute_curve(f,-0.4,1.4,0.001) scaled u;
  draw curve withcolor white ;

  path rectangle;
  rectangle := (-0.3u,-0.4u) -- (1.3u,-0.4u) -- (1.3u,-0.4u) -- (1.3u,1.4u) -- (-0.3u,1.4u)--cycle;

  clip currentpicture to rectangle;
  draw rectangle withpen pencircle scaled 3 withcolor darkred ;
\stopMPpage



In fact, the problem seems to come from my pdf reader which is Evince because even the graph you proposed is not visible. On the other hand, if I use Okular, for example, the graph is clearly visible. Sorry for the noise !

Yes, but you can probably do better with the clipping. Maybe work a bit more when drawing so that you do not have to clip.
